# Difference between Libsvm and vl_feat SVM

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm, vlfeat

I am working on image classification project. I utilized Lib-SVM and Vl_feat SVM implementation train a linear kernel. Both classifiers returns different result can some one explain what is the  different between two libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at the websites for the two implementations, they use different algorithms to solve the SVM problem.  That is, both are SVM's but one uses one trick to find the weights, and the other uses a different trick.  The results should both be similar, but not exactly the same.

Another possible difference is the parameters you are passing in to the implementations.  The different libraries may have different default settings for certain parameters you are not explicitly setting.